# Unrecognized argument type to convert to an Image: function(){var d=Ga.apply(0,arguments)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to make a linear correlation using the time series MODIS LST data in three months. Each image is composed of a band,  to calculate the correlation between an image (27 Sep 2019) and other images, the results are listed separately.

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-xrpt/assets/studyarea");
Map.centerObject(roi,10);
var styling={color:'green', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(roi.style(styling),{},'roi');
// Import a MODIS LST image for this region.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
              .filterBounds(roi)
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-9-01', '2020-03-01'))
              //.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',1)
var landSurfaceTemperature = collection.select('LST_Day_1km');

// select image in 9.27 from image collection 
var image = ee.Image('MODIS/061/MOD11A1/2019_09_26')
Map.centerObject(roi,10);
var rgbVis = {
  band: ['0'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1000000000000000000
};
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), rgbVis, 'Multi-band RGB image');
print ('All band names', image.bandNames());

// Create a new image that is the concatenation of three images: a constant,
// the 26th band, and the other bands.
var constant = ee.Image(1);
var xVar = landSurfaceTemperature.select(image);
var img = landSurfaceTemperature
var yVar = img.select('b2');

 error occurred in bellow code: Unrecognized argument type to convert to an Image: function(){var d=Ga.apply(0,arguments).map(function(e){return c.ir(e)});d=dSa(c,a,d);return c.jj(d)}

var imgRegress = ee.Image.cat(constant, xVar, yVar);
// Calculate regression coefficients for the set of pixels intersecting the
// above defined region using reduceRegion. The numX parameter is set as 2
// because the constant and the SWIR1 bands are independent variables and they
// are the first two bands in the stack; numY is set as 1 because there is only
// one dependent variable (SWIR2) and it follows as band three in the stack.
var linearRegression = imgRegress.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
    numX: 2,
    numY: 1
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 1000,
});
 //for all images
 var a = imgRegress.map(linearRegression);
 
// Convert the coefficients array to a list.
var coefList = ee.Array(linearRegression.get('coefficients')).toList();

var b0 = ee.List(coefList.get(0)).get(0); // y-intercept
var b1 = ee.List(coefList.get(1)).get(0); // slope
// Extract the residuals.
var residuals = ee.Array(linearRegression.get('residuals')).toList().get(0);

// Inspect the results.
print('OLS estimates', linearRegression);
print('y-intercept:', b0);
print('Slope:', b1);
print('Residuals:', residuals);hjgjh
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this script, to the degree that I cannot understand what it's trying to achieve. Please update your question and explain the steps you're trying to take in detail. Also, clean up the script to the best of your ability and provide a link to the script in the code editor (using the `Get Link` button).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will edit it. Thanks again.